# Cómo consultar datos de una BBDD e insertar dichos datos en la otra BBDD

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

A ver, tengo dos bases de datos, cada una en un servidor distinto. Una es un MySQL, otra un MS Access. El caso es que ya tengo un array que me saca todos los IDPedidos que están en MS Access que no están en MySQL. Por tanto, ahora básicamente tengo que:

1º) SELECT que me devuelva todos los campos a la bbdd de MS Access según IdPedido. 
2º) INSERT que me inserte todos los registros de cada IdPedido en la tabla de MySQL.

No sé cuál es la forma más óptima de hacerla. ¿Usaríais una variable intermedia para guardar los datos del primer select y luego hacer el INSERT? ¿O se puede hacer el SELECT y el INSERT seguido sin guardar los datos en una variable? Por si alguien me va a comentar que lo ideal sería usar transacciones de SQL, no me dejan utilizarlas para esto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo personalmente utilizaría una variable intermedia para asegurar el correcto funcionamiento

Comment: Las preguntas amplias y basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: De acuerdo, no lo sabía, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Toma todos los ID de pedido y haz una consulta `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE idPedido IN (id1, id2, idX)` y en un ciclo lees los resultados e insertas en la otra tabla.

Comment: Por ahora estoy probando con este código foreach ($arrayCambiosMS as $key => $value) {
            $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido="SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido=$arrayCambiosMS[$value]";
            $ejecMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querySelectMSdiffIdPedido);
            $datosToInsertMySQL=odbc_fetch_row($ejecMS);
        }

        var_dump($datosToInsertMySQL); " pero me da errores, no sé pq. Me dice que  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] Pocos par�metros. Se esperaba 1., SQL state 07001 y otro error que se llama...

Comment: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluir el código que has publicado en los comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;

Sí, claro que se puede hacer un select con un insert y de hecho se hace muy a menudo.

Ejemplo:
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';